I keep getting Instance of SongEntity in my firebase project
Im trying to fetch a list of songs from firebase and add them all to a list of songs
Code for the SongEntity
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SongEntity {
  final String songId;
  final String title;
  final String artist;
  final String link;
  final String imageUrl;

  SongEntity({
    required this.songId,
    required this.title,
    required this.artist,
    required this.link,
    required this.imageUrl,
  });

  factory SongEntity.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return SongEntity(
      songId: doc.id,
      title: data['title'],
      artist: data['artist'],
      link: data['link'],
      imageUrl: data['image'],
    );
  }
}
 

Code for the PlaylistProvider class that has the function to get the songs from firestore
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../domain/entities/song_entities/song_entity.dart';

class PlaylistProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<SongEntity> _songs = [];

  List<SongEntity> get songs => _songs;

  getPlaylistFromFirestore(String collectionName, String playlistName) async {
    final fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await fireStore.collection(collectionName).get().then(
      (querySnapshot) {
        for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
          print('${docSnapshot.id} => ${docSnapshot.data()['artist']}');
          _songs.add(SongEntity.fromDocument(docSnapshot));
          notifyListeners();
        }
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
  }
}


This part of the code works perfectly and all documents are printed out
  print('${docSnapshot.id} => ${docSnapshot.data()['artist']}');

But when i try to print the value of songs from my homepage
    print(Provider.of<PlaylistProvider>(context).songs);


I get this in console

I/flutter (10936): [Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity', Instance of 'SongEntity']

Any help will be greatly appreciated

I want to add that the data coming from firebase doesnt have a songId field like the songentity does,Instead i am just feeding the songId data from the response generated by the getPlaylistfromfirestore function as seen in the code. Also i am not using a field coming from firebase called duration. I hope that doesnt have anything to do with the error im getting.

Since you're printing the list of songs, it executes the toString of your SongEntity class - which defaults to the output you see.
If you want to show a different output, override the toString method in your SongEntity class. For example, like this:
class SongEntity {
  ...
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'SongEntity(songId: $songId, title: $title, artist: $artist, link: $link, imageUrl: $imageUrl)';
  }
}

For a good explanation of toString, see What does @override toString method do in a Flutter Dart class?

Can you please provide the code to do that? All i need is for the songs list to be populated with the list of songs mapped from firebase.

Done. Please spend some time reading up on toString, as you're likely to need to do this regularly.

Thank you. But i have another question. Say i want to provide the songs list to another part of my app, How would i access the data inside the songs list without using the print statement? Like say i want each song entity to be displayed in a listtile and populate the leading, title and trailing accordingly. I dont think the list i created to store the songs behaves like a normal flutter list where i can print everything or access data by index.

List<SongEntity> _songs = []; looks like a pretty standard List to me. If you're passing that object elsewhere and have a hard time accessing it, I recommend posting a new question with its own minimal repro.
